# Go Template Extra line on the Range

Tags: go, go-templates

I have Following go Template code

```
    custom_listeners:  {{ range $cl := $.Vars.CustomListeners }}
      {{ $cl.ListenerType }}:
        {{ range $k,$v := $cl.Values }}{{ $k }}: "{{ $v }}"
        {{ end }}{{ end }}
```

Which creates the following YAML file . However the looping through the services add extra line between the service. I have tried different method to remove this line but it messes the yml formatting.

```
    custom_listeners:
      service1:
        name: "service1"
        port: "8091"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
                            <-------------------------- Extra Line
      service2:
        name: "service2"
        port: "8092"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
                             <-------------------------- Extra Line
      service3:
        name: "service3"
        port: "9093"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
```

Just wondering what would be the best to way to get Desired result below :

```
    custom_listeners:
      service1:
        name: "service1"
        port: "8091"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
      service2:
        name: "service2"
        port: "8092"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
      service3:
        name: "service3"
        port: "7093"
        ssl_enabled: "false"
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried all possible way by adding - , it messes the yml formatting

Answer (score 2):

https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Text_and_spaces

> ... if an action's left delimiter (by default "{{") is followed
> immediately by a minus sign and white space, *all trailing white space
> is trimmed from the immediately **preceding** text*. Similarly, if the
> right delimiter ("}}") is preceded by white space and a minus sign,
> all leading white space is trimmed from the immediately following
> text. ...

```
custom_listeners:
{{- range $cl := $.Vars.CustomListeners }}
    {{ $cl.ListenerType }}:
        {{- range $k,$v := $cl.Values }}
        {{ $k }}: "{{ $v }}"
        {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/aZ7tNqV2Phq

Comment: Hi @mkopriva worked like a magic:) Really Appreciate